Change sysctl based on certain conditions
I set kernel.deny_new_usb=1 via /etc/sysctl.d/params.conf, but that's inconvenient of course.
I would like to make kernel.deny_new_usb=0 when the user is logged in and the KDE screen is not locked. When there is no user logged in or the KDE screen is locked, I want kernel.deny_new_usb=1.
I've been thinking on writing a shell script to check these things and apply sysctl accordingly, then run this script as a daemon. Problem is that I am worried about battery usage with this checks running all the time and I am struggling to find a optimal way to accomplish this. Udev seems like a good way, but I guess it is not able to check if users are logged in and KDE screen isn't locked.
My main goal is to use this sysctl flag to completely disable the USB subsystem when the user is nowhere near.

There may be a way run a command when you screen is locked/unlocked.

You can either use usbguard or create a shell script which interacts with dbus (this is what dbus is for) so you can get notifications of events and do the locking/unlocking of usb using sysctl commands based on events you receive from dbus. Waiting on events on dbus won’t affect your battery, it’s what the whole GUI uses for event notifications.
There is also a good article about this in general here: https://access.redhat.com/articles/3230621
